# txt file descriptor in lsof

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, lsof

In my experience, files that have the file descriptor of `txt` in `lsof` output are the executable file itself and shared objects.  The `lsof` man page says that it means "program text (code and data)".

While debugging a problem, I found a large number of data files (specifically, ElasticSearch database index files) that `lsof` reported as `txt`.  These are definitely not executable files.  The process was ElasticSearch itself, which is a java process, if that helps point someone in the right direction.

I want to understand how this process is opening and using these files that gets it to be reported in this way. I'm trying to understand some memory utilization, and I suspect that these open files are related to some metrics I'm seeing in some way.

The system is Solaris 10 x86.

Comment: To track down whatever problem you're pursuing I'm not sure I would use `lsof` on Solaris. That command is something of a hack on Solaris which is why it isn't included in the OS by default. The true alternatives on Solaris would be `pfiles` command and DTrace. Using the latter you can monitor for example file operations in real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Solaris, everything that is mapped into the memory space of the process will be listed by `lsof` as `txt`, regardless of being the started executable, or an executable shared object mapped by ld.so, or any data file mapped directly by the application.

On Linux, only the started executable will be listed as `txt`, everything else mapped into the memory space will be shown as `mem` (both executable shared objects and data files).

Comment: Interesting.  The `lsof` documentation says that `mmap()`ed files will be reported as `mem`, but [a quick test program](http://pastebin.com/fPPTVrAH) shows me that [that's not the case](http://pastebin.com/C2ZKpLQD).

Comment: Specifically, `mmap()`ed files that still have a file descriptor open are referenced by that file descriptor and `mmap()`ed files whose file descriptors have been closed are reported as `txt`.